# How to define exception to be thrown through ref in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Have to throw an exception in my camel route defined in XML. Found `throwException` statement available from Camel 2.3 which looks like:

```
 <throwException ref="forced"></throwException>
```

However, I don't know how to define `forced` exception class to be thrown. Since same exception could be thrown couple of times with different exception messages - would be good to know if `throwException` has some other form of definition so exception class and exception message are defined in-place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ref is just a reference to a  so you can do

```
<bean id="forced" class="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="This is forced"/>
</bean>

<camelContext ...>
  ...
</camelContext>
```

Comment: You can also look in the src/test/java directory of the source code of camel-spring, to find examples how to use <throwException> in XML

Answer (score 15):

Since version 2.16.0 there is more elegant way to do it, with optional exception message:

```
<route>
     <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" message="illegal argument found"/>
</route>
```