# Rethrow CXF exception in camel with onException

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to catch and reformat (hide info) for an exception in camel thrown from a cxf webservice call. [ThrowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839612/how-to-define-exception-to-be-thrown-through-ref-in-apache-camel)... what should I throw then.

This does not work since the transform is not working (of course). What is the best way?

```
 <camel:onException>
    <camel:exception>org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault</camel:exception>
    <camel:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" delay="5000"/>
    <camel:handled>
            <camel:constant>true</camel:constant>
    </camel:handled>
    <camel:transform>
      <camel:simple>Cannot process this message. Retry later. </camel:simple>
    </camel:transform>
 </camel:onException>

<camel:route trace="false" id="LEFIIncoming">
    <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:PostSpecIn" />
    <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:PostSpecOut" />
</camel:route>
```

Comment: claus ... var är du :)=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the response message to a response type the CXF web service expects/supports. So look at the WSDL from your "cxf:bean:PostSpecIn" and either return a SOAP Fault as response, or some response type that the out message supports.

Comment: OK, so return a soap fault tag, within the simple, will try thanks.

Comment: Remember to mark the message as a soap fault, using < setFaultBody >