# How can I fail a camel-route when exec returns nonzero?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm processing files with a Camel route like this:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:inbox?delete=true"/>
        <recipientList>
            <simple>exec://process.sh?args=inbox/${file:name}</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <log message="processed ${file:name}: ${body.stdout} ${body.stderr}"/>
    </route>
```

Now I'd like the route to fail when `process.sh` finishes with nonzero exit-code. I found `${headers.CamelExecExitValue}` but don't really know what to do with it.

In the example above, the file should not get deleted when `process.sh` fails. In my actual use-case, the route consumes files from a JMS queue and I want the file to stay in the queue. I think this can be done with `<transacted/>` but need to know how to fail the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [How to define exception to be thrown through ref in Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839612/how-to-define-exception-to-be-thrown-through-ref-in-apache-camel) which in combination with `CamelExecExitValue` lets me abort this way:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:inbox?delete=true"/>
        <to uri="exec://process.sh"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>
                    ${headers.CamelExecExitValue} != 0
                </simple>
                <throwException exceptionType="java.lang.RuntimeException" message="failed importing ${file:name}: ${body.stdout} ${body.stderr}"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
        <log message="processed ${file:name}"/>
    </route>
```

A bit verbose for my taste but works fine.